# specifying u-boot in reserved-memory node in kernel dts

Tags: kernel, u-boot, device-tree

What is the use of adding `u-boot` entry to `reserved-memory` node in kernel dts? should it have any impact when we collect the ram dump? Like this for example:

```
reserved-memory{         
  uboot@41000000{
   reg=<0x4000000 0x20000>
   nomap;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of reserved-memory by Linux is explained here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt

The above reserved memory declaration is incorrect as the address in the name does not match the start address in reg.

There is no need to declare any reserved memory for U-Boot in a dts file.

Comment: if we don't reserve the memory for u-boot, will the kernel data be populated in that region?

Comment: Once Linux is booted no memory is used by U-Boot at all, except if you have booted via UEFI using the bootefi comand. In this case U-Boot will communicate the memory that is occupied by the EFI runtime to the operating system via the memory map. The location of the EFI runtime is determined at runtime and can not be prescribed a device tree node. What made you think that such a devicetree entry should be created?

Comment: why i have added the reserved node for the u-boot in the kernel dts is,kernel will leave the u-boot region and when we collect the complete RAM dump at the time of crash. we will get the u-boot also. that is the idea behind the adding of that dts node. Thanks for spending some time for me.